# When does Aspect of the Beast apply?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

My character has reached level 6 and I'd like to use the eagle as my totem animal when I take on the Aspect of the Beast. I says I can see up to 1 mile away with no difficultly and dim light doesn't impose a disadvantage on perception checks.

What I'd like to know if is this in effect all the time or only when I'm raging? Would I get extra benefits when combing this with the use of a telescope (I believe the PHB refers to it as a spyglass)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### This effect is not dependent upon Raging

In the 3rd level Totem Spirit benefits, all three entries start with "While (you're) raging."  These effects are obviously only active during Rage.  The 14th level benefits are also worded to only be active "While you're raging".

The 6th level benefits simply state "You gain," and make no mention of the abilities being tied to rage.

Since there has been no published errata on the subject, the rules are interpreted as they are written - you permanently gain the chosen bonus.

The PHB states that using a spyglass magnifies objects to twice their size.  A normal character would not be able to see further using a spyglass (RAW), only able to more accurately discern what he/she is viewing. While I would personally ask your GM beforehand, there appears to be nothing prohibiting you from being able to use your increased ability to see detail combined with a spyglass.

Comment: I was just wondering if using a spyglass with my eagle eyed vision whether I would gain any benefits over a normal person using a spyglass.

Comment: I tried to clarify - hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that with my DM. I'm guessing in most cases I'll be fine without one.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes the 1 mile vision is active all the time**.

This is the 3rd level benefit :

> **Eagle**. While you’re raging and aren’t wearing heavy armor, other
>   creatures have disadvantage on opportunity attack rolls against you,
>   and you can use the Dash action as a bonus action on your turn. The
>   spirit of the eagle makes you into a predator who can weave through
>   the fray with ease.

It specify that the bonus is taking effect while you're raging.

This is the 6th level benefit :

> **Eagle**. You gain the eyesight of an eagle. You can see up to 1 mile away with
>   no difficulty, able to discern even fine details as though looking at
>   something no more than 100 feet away from you. Additionally, dim light
>   doesn’t impose disadvantage on your Wisdom (Perception) checks.

It does not require you to rage to gain the benefit so the enhanced vision is **passive**

For the spyglass I would say that you would see the exact same thing with or without the Eagle vision, as your sharp vision stops at the beginning of the looking end of the spyglass.